# Doctrine/Symfony2 bidirectionnal manyToMany : one direction fail

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've been scratchnig my head on the following problem but can't figure it out.

I have 2 entites (Utilisateur, Residence) linked by a bidirectionnal manyToMany relationship.

When I want to get residences from a user, it's OK

```
$user = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Utilisateur')->findOneById(3);
$residences = $user->getUtilisateurResidences();
```

But When I want to get users from residence it fails

```
$residence = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Residence')->findOneById(3);
$negociateurs = $residence->getResidenceUtilisateurs();
```

with the following erros :

```
Could not convert database value "" to Doctrine Type array
C:\wamp64\www\chronos-2017\src\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException.php
```

Funny things is that when i do the same manyToMany declaration for tests entities (Owner and Inverse below), it just work fine so it should come from one of my entity or orm yml configuration file.

Owning side

```
AppBundle\Entity\Owner:
type: entity
table: null
repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\OwnerRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    nom:
        type: string
        length: 255
manyToMany:
    ownerInverses:
        targetEntity: Inverse
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: inverseOwners
        inversedBy: null
        joinTable: null
        orderBy: null
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Inverse side

```
AppBundle\Entity\Inverse:
type: entity
table: null
repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\InverseRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    nom:
        type: string
        length: 255
manyToMany:
    inverseOwners:
        targetEntity: Owner
        cascade: ["persist"]
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        orderBy: null
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

I off course update my entites and database before testing 
by running the commands :

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entites AppBundle

app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql (or --force)
```

I tried to swich the owning side of the relationship, didn't work
I tried another way for manyToMany declaration => failed (see owner and inverse above)

I wanted to delete both entities and recreate them but my entity utilisateur is used for connection and many other things and it just blows up my entire application if I do so.

Anyone has a clue of how to resolve it?

Thanks :-)

Below are my enties files (entities + yml configuration files)

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use AppBundle\Entity\Residence;
use AppBundle\Entity\Role;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use FR3D\LdapBundle\Model\LdapUserInterface as LdapUserInterface;

class Utilisateur extends BaseUser implements LdapUserInterface
{
    protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $dn;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $login;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $prenom;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $telephone;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $image;

/**
 * @var boolean
 */
private $indActif;

/**
 * @var boolean
 */
private $indRepartitionAleatoire;

/**
 * @var boolean
 */
private $indArchive;

/**
 * @var Role
 */
private $role;


/**
 * Set login
 *
 * @param string $login
 *
 * @return Utilisateur
 */
public function setLogin($login)
{
    $this->login = $login;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get login
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLogin()
{
    return $this->login;
}

/**
 * Set nom
 *
 * @param string $nom
 *
 * @return Utilisateur
 */
public function setNom($nom)
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nom
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNom()
{
    return $this->nom;
}

/**
 * Set prenom
 *
 * @param string $prenom
 *
 * @return Utilisateur
 */
public function setPrenom($prenom)
{
    $this->prenom = $prenom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get prenom
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPrenom()
{
    return $this->prenom;
}

/**
 * Set telephone
 *
 * @param string $telephone
 *
 * @return Utilisateur
 */
public function setTelephone($telephone)
{
    $this->telephone = $telephone;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get telephone
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTelephone()
{
    return $this->telephone;
}

/**
 * Set image
 *
 * @param string $image
 *
 * @return Utilisateur
 */
public function setImage($image)
{
    $this->image = $image;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get image
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getImage()
{
    return $this->image;
}

/**
 * Set indActif
 *
 * @param boolean $indActif
 *
 * @return Utilisateur
 */
public function setIndActif($indActif)
{
    $this->indActif = $indActif;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get indActif
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getIndActif()
{
    return $this->indActif;
}

/**
 * Set indRepartitionAleatoire
 *
 * @param boolean $indRepartitionAleatoire
 *
 * @return Utilisateur
 */
public function setIndRepartitionAleatoire($indRepartitionAleatoire)
{
    $this->indRepartitionAleatoire = $indRepartitionAleatoire;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get indRepartitionAleatoire
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getIndRepartitionAleatoire()
{
    return $this->indRepartitionAleatoire;
}

/**
 * Set indArchive
 *
 * @param boolean $indArchive
 *
 * @return Utilisateur
 */
public function setIndArchive($indArchive)
{
    $this->indArchive = $indArchive;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get indArchive
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getIndArchive()
{
    return $this->indArchive;
}

/**
 * Set role
 *
 * @param Role $role
 *
 * @return Utilisateur
 */
public function setRole(Role $role = null)
{
    $this->role = $role;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get role
 *
 * @return Role
 */
public function getRole()
{
    return $this->role;
}

public function setDn($dn)
{
    $this->dn = $dn;
}

public function getDn()
{
    return $this->dn;
}

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $residence_remplacants;


/**
 * Add residenceRemplacant
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Utilisateur $residenceRemplacant
 *
 * @return Utilisateur
 */
public function addResidenceRemplacant(Utilisateur $residenceRemplacant)
{
    $this->residence_remplacants[] = $residenceRemplacant;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove residenceRemplacant
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Utilisateur $residenceRemplacant
 */
public function removeResidenceRemplacant(Utilisateur $residenceRemplacant)
{
    $this->residence_remplacants->removeElement($residenceRemplacant);
}

/**
 * Get residenceRemplacants
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getResidenceRemplacants()
{
    return $this->residence_remplacants;
}
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $utilisateurResidences;


/**
 * Add utilisateurResidence
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Residence $utilisateurResidence
 *
 * @return Utilisateur
 */
public function addUtilisateurResidence(\AppBundle\Entity\Residence $utilisateurResidence)
{
    $this->utilisateurResidences[] = $utilisateurResidence;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove utilisateurResidence
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Residence $utilisateurResidence
 */
public function removeUtilisateurResidence(\AppBundle\Entity\Residence $utilisateurResidence)
{
    $this->utilisateurResidences->removeElement($utilisateurResidence);
}

/**
 * Get utilisateurResidences
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getUtilisateurResidences()
{
    return $this->utilisateurResidences;
}
```

}

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use AppBundle\Entity\Utilisateur;


/**
 * Residence
 *
 */
class Residence
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $codeImmeuble;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $adresse;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $cp;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $ville;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $tel;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $hermesId;

/**
 * @var boolean
 */
private $nbMoisDepotGarantie;

/**
 * @var float
 */
private $mntKitNuit;

/**
 * @var boolean
 */
private $termePaiementLoyerProp = '1';

/**
 * @var boolean
 */
private $periodicitePaiementLoyer = '3';

/**
 * @var boolean
 */
private $indArchive = false;

/**
 * @var Utilisateur
 */
private $responsable;

/**
 * @var Utilisateur
 */
private $gestionnaire;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\SecteurResidence
 */
private $secteur;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $dossierClient;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->dossierClient = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->negociateurs = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set codeImmeuble
 *
 * @param string $codeImmeuble
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setCodeImmeuble($codeImmeuble)
{
    $this->codeImmeuble = $codeImmeuble;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get codeImmeuble
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCodeImmeuble()
{
    return $this->codeImmeuble;
}

/**
 * Set nom
 *
 * @param string $nom
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setNom($nom)
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nom
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNom()
{
    return $this->nom;
}

/**
 * Set adresse
 *
 * @param string $adresse
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setAdresse($adresse)
{
    $this->adresse = $adresse;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get adresse
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAdresse()
{
    return $this->adresse;
}

/**
 * Set cp
 *
 * @param string $cp
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setCp($cp)
{
    $this->cp = $cp;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get cp
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCp()
{
    return $this->cp;
}

/**
 * Set ville
 *
 * @param string $ville
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setVille($ville)
{
    $this->ville = $ville;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get ville
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getVille()
{
    return $this->ville;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getTel()
{
    return $this->tel;
}

/**
 * @param string $tel
 */
public function setTel($tel)
{
    $this->tel = $tel;
}


/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set commentaire
 *
 * @param string $commentaire
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setCommentaire($commentaire)
{
    $this->commentaire = $commentaire;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get commentaire
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCommentaire()
{
    return $this->commentaire;
}

/**
 * Set hermesId
 *
 * @param integer $hermesId
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setHermesId($hermesId)
{
    $this->hermesId = $hermesId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get hermesId
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getHermesId()
{
    return $this->hermesId;
}

/**
 * Set nbMoisDepotGarantie
 *
 * @param boolean $nbMoisDepotGarantie
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setNbMoisDepotGarantie($nbMoisDepotGarantie)
{
    $this->nbMoisDepotGarantie = $nbMoisDepotGarantie;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nbMoisDepotGarantie
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getNbMoisDepotGarantie()
{
    return $this->nbMoisDepotGarantie;
}

/**
 * Set mntKitNuit
 *
 * @param float $mntKitNuit
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setMntKitNuit($mntKitNuit)
{
    $this->mntKitNuit = $mntKitNuit;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get mntKitNuit
 *
 * @return float
 */
public function getMntKitNuit()
{
    return $this->mntKitNuit;
}


/**
 * Set termePaiementLoyerProp
 *
 * @param smallint $termePaiementLoyerProp
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setTermePaiementLoyerProp($termePaiementLoyerProp)
{
    $this->termePaiementLoyerProp = $termePaiementLoyerProp;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get termePaiementLoyerProp
 *
 * @return smallint
 */
public function getTermePaiementLoyerProp()
{
    return $this->termePaiementLoyerProp;
}

/**
 * Set periodicitePaiementLoyer
 *
 * @param smallint $periodicitePaiementLoyer
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setPeriodicitePaiementLoyer($periodicitePaiementLoyer)
{
    $this->periodicitePaiementLoyer = $periodicitePaiementLoyer;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get periodicitePaiementLoyer
 *
 * @return smallint
 */
public function getPeriodicitePaiementLoyer()
{
    return $this->periodicitePaiementLoyer;
}

/**
 * Set indArchive
 *
 * @param boolean $indArchive
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setIndArchive($indArchive)
{
    $this->indArchive = $indArchive;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get indArchive
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getIndArchive()
{
    return $this->indArchive;
}

/**
 * Set responsable
 *
 * @param Utilisateur $responsable
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setResponsable(Utilisateur $responsable = null)
{
    $this->responsable = $responsable;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get responsable
 *
 * @return Utilisateur
 */
public function getResponsable()
{
    return $this->responsable;
}

/**
 * Set gestionnaire
 *
 * @param Utilisateur $gestionnaire
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setGestionnaire(Utilisateur $gestionnaire = null)
{
    $this->gestionnaire = $gestionnaire;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get gestionnaire
 *
 * @return Utilisateur
 */
public function getGestionnaire()
{
    return $this->gestionnaire;
}

/**
 * Set secteur
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\SecteurResidence $secteur
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setSecteur(\AppBundle\Entity\SecteurResidence $secteur = null)
{
    $this->secteur = $secteur;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get secteur
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\SecteurResidence
 */
public function getSecteur()
{
    return $this->secteur;
}

/**
 * Add dossierClient
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\DossierClient $dossierClient
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function addDossierClient(\AppBundle\Entity\DossierClient $dossierClient)
{
    $this->dossierClient[] = $dossierClient;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove dossierClient
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\DossierClient $dossierClient
 */
public function removeDossierClient(\AppBundle\Entity\DossierClient $dossierClient)
{
    $this->dossierClient->removeElement($dossierClient);
}

/**
 * Get dossierClient
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getDossierClient()
{
    return $this->dossierClient;
}

/**
 * Add utilisateur
 *
 * @param Utilisateur $utilisateur
 *
 * @return Residence
 */

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $adresseComplement;


/**
 * Set adresseComplement
 *
 * @param string $adresseComplement
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function setAdresseComplement($adresseComplement)
{
    $this->adresseComplement = $adresseComplement;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get adresseComplement
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAdresseComplement()
{
    return $this->adresseComplement;
}

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $remplacants;


/**
 * Add remplacant
 *
 * @param Utilisateur $remplacant
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function addRemplacant(Utilisateur $remplacant)
{
    $this->remplacants[] = $remplacant;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove remplacant
 *
 * @param Utilisateur $remplacant
 */
public function removeRemplacant(Utilisateur $remplacant)
{
    $this->remplacants->removeElement($remplacant);
}

/**
 * Get remplacants
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getRemplacants()
{
    return $this->remplacants;
}
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $residenceUtilisateurs;


/**
 * Add residenceUtilisateur
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Utilisateur $residenceUtilisateur
 *
 * @return Residence
 */
public function addResidenceUtilisateur(\AppBundle\Entity\Utilisateur $residenceUtilisateur)
{
    $this->residenceUtilisateurs[] = $residenceUtilisateur;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove residenceUtilisateur
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Utilisateur $residenceUtilisateur
 */
public function removeResidenceUtilisateur(\AppBundle\Entity\Utilisateur $residenceUtilisateur)
{
    $this->residenceUtilisateurs->removeElement($residenceUtilisateur);
}

/**
 * Get residenceUtilisateurs
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getResidenceUtilisateurs()
{
    return $this->residenceUtilisateurs;
}
```

}

```
AppBundle\Entity\Utilisateur:
type: entity
repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\UtilisateurRepository
table: utilisateur
indexes:
    fk_utilisateur_roler_id_idx:
        columns:
            - role_id
uniqueConstraints:
    UNIQ_1D1C63B392FC23A8:
        columns:
            - username_canonical
    UNIQ_1D1C63B3A0D96FBF:
        columns:
            - email_canonical
    UNIQ_1D1C63B3C05FB297:
        columns:
            - confirmation_token
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        options:
            unsigned: false
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
fields:
    nom:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: 255
        options:
            fixed: false
    prenom:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: 255
        options:
            fixed: false
    telephone:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
    image:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 255
        options:
            fixed: false
    indRepartitionAleatoire:
        type: boolean
        nullable: true
        column: ind_repartition_aleatoire
    indArchive:
        type: boolean
        nullable: true
        column: ind_archive
    dn:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: 255
        options:
            fixed: false
manyToOne:
    role:
        targetEntity: Role
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            role_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
manyToMany:
    residence_remplacants:
        targetEntity: Residence
        mappedBy: remplacants
    utilisateurResidences:
        targetEntity: Residence
        mappedBy: residenceUtilisateurs
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }


AppBundle\Entity\Residence:
type: entity
repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\ResidenceRepository
table: residence
uniqueConstraints:
        slug:
            columns:
                - code_immeuble
indexes:
    fk_immeuble_resp_id_idx:
        columns:
            - responsable_id
    fk_immeuble_resp_administratif_id_idx:
        columns:
            - gestionnaire_id
    fk_residence_ville_id_idx:
        columns:
            - secteur_id
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        options:
            unsigned: false
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
fields:
    codeImmeuble:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: 2
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: code_immeuble
    nom:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: 255
        options:
            fixed: false
    adresse:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 255
        options:
            fixed: false
    adresseComplement:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 255
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: adresse_complement
    cp:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 5
        options:
            fixed: false
    ville:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 255
        options:
            fixed: false
    tel:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: tel
    email:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 255
        options:
            fixed: false
    commentaire:
        type: text
        nullable: true
        length: 65535
        options:
            fixed: false
    slug:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 64
        options:
            fixed: false
    image:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 255
        options:
            fixed: false
    dateOuverture:
        type: date
        nullable: true
        column: date_ouverture
    dateLivraison:
        type: date
        nullable: true
        column: date_livraison
    hermesId:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
        options:
            unsigned: false
        column: hermes_id
    nbMoisDepotGarantie:
        type: smallint
        nullable: true
        column: nb_mois_depot_garantie
    mntKitNuit:
        type: float
        nullable: true
        precision: 10
        scale: 0
        column: mnt_kit_nuit
    termePaiementLoyerProp:
        type: smallint
        nullable: true
        options:
            comment: '1 : échu, 2 : a echoir'
            default: '1'
        column: terme_paiement_loyer_prop
    periodicitePaiementLoyer:
        type: smallint
        nullable: true
        options:
            default: '3'
        column: periodicite_paiement_loyer
    indArchive:
        type: boolean
        nullable: false
        options:
            default: false
        column: ind_archive
manyToOne:
    gestionnaire:
        targetEntity: Utilisateur
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            gestionnaire_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
    responsable:
        targetEntity: Utilisateur
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            responsable_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
    secteur:
        targetEntity: SecteurResidence
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            secteur_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
manyToMany:
    dossierClient:
        targetEntity: DossierClient
        mappedBy: residence

    residenceUtilisateurs:
        targetEntity: Utilisateur
        inversedBy: utilisateurResidences
        joinTable:
            name: residence_utilisateurs
            joinColumns:
                residence_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                utilisateur_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id

    remplacants:
        targetEntity: Utilisateur
        inversedBy: residence_remplacants
        joinTable:
            name: residence_remplacant
            joinColumns:
                -
                    name: residence_id
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                -
                    name: utilisateur_id
                    referencedColumnName: id
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: Just a quick shot in the dark here - but have you tried adding __toString() methods to both entities?

Comment: I think you should declare all your properties at the top of your class to make your code more readable. You should also instanciate residenceUtilisateurs and utilisateurResidences as ArrayCollection in a __construct method (just like you did for dossierClients and negociateurs in utilisateur entity). Finally, which case do you encounter the most : adding new utilisateurs to a residence or adding new residences to an utilisateur ?

Comment: Hi, thxs for your help :). Turned out the code was fine, it was my database that was messed up.  with another database it works